# creating a 2 column table dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate a table dynamically using ajax call. To simplify things i have just added my code to js fiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/5yLrE/81/

As you click on the button "HI" first two columns are created properly.. but some how as the td length reaches 2 . its not creating another row. The reason is that when i do find on the table elements its actually retrieving the children table elements. Can some one pls help.

I want a two column table.. Thank you.

sample code:

```
var tr = $("#maintable tbody tr:first");

if(!tr.length || tr.find("td:first").length >= max) {
    $("#maintable").append("<tr>");
}
if(count==0) {
    $("#maintable tr:last").append("<td>hi"+content+"</td>");
}
```

Comment: Looking at your sample code, you really want to start using some form of templating and not inline HTML strings. e.g. create a dummy `script` section with an unknown `type="text/template"` and put your template HTML in that. You can reference that script element by id and get the `html()` to copy/insert.

Comment: Hi TrueBlueAussie. Yes i do use templating its just for the jsfiddle purpose i have written the code that way. and can you elaborate more how can i use the html property. I mean i dont understand how that solves the purpose.

Comment: `tr.find("td:first")` will always return 0 or 1 element (because of the `:first`)

Comment: I forgot to make that code change. Count variable is not used anymore.  The fiddle is edited now. However thats not the problem.. if you can check the fiddle carefully please.

Comment: Hi Ian, that what you suggest me to do. making it just "td" returns the children table count too . it ll show 3.. instead of 2.

Comment: @user1908568 Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6UyZ3/

Comment: Thank you Ian. It worked fine. I got it. I was just trying to resolve the current code without taking efforts to think new. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the matching of descendants was allowing for great great grandchildren etc. Just needed to make the matching more specific.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5yLrE/91/

```
max = 2
$("button").click(function () {
    var content = $('#template').html();
    var $table = $("#maintable");
    var tr = $table.find(">tbody>tr:last");
    if (!tr.length || tr.find(">td").length >= max) {
        // Append a blank row
        tr = $("<tr>");
        $table.append(tr);
    }
    tr.append("<td>hi " + content + "</td>");
});
```

This one *always targets the last row* and adds a row if it does not exists at all (or there are too many divs already) which is what I gather you intended.

*I also used the templating I suggested to separate messy HTML strings from the code.*

Comment: Thank you Ian and TrueBlueAussie. Both the fiddles work fine!! I appreciate. you are right .. that is what happened it was taking decedents precedence. this is another correct fiddle link by IAN :  jsfiddle.net/6UyZ3

Answer (score 1):

You will want to check the length of the table cells before incrementing a new table row. After you have reached your max column length, reset the row and start over.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yLrE/93/)

```
max_columns = 2;
count=0;
$("button").click(function() {
    var content='column';
    if(count==max_columns||!$('#maintable tr').length){
        $("#maintable").append("<tr>");
        count=0;
    }
    if(count!=max_columns)
        $("#maintable tr:last").append("<td>"+content+"</td>");
    else
        $("#maintable tr:first").append("<td>"+content+"</td>");
    count++;
});
```

Comment: Matt the code you gave fails if i create another table. Try replacing the content variable defined in the question and see the effect. see here http://jsfiddle.net/5yLrE/95/

Comment: nice catch! i didn't account for nested tables